# Bendy Bone: Ends of mesh doesn't curve

Tags: bones

The bendy bone is connected by automatic weights but the end of the mesh doesn't curve with the rest of the mesh.[image: A picture of the bendy bone being shown][image: A visual of how the curve stops and goes straight in the mesh.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all bones will deform the mesh.

The simplest way is probably to unparent the mesh, uncheck "deform" in the bone properties for the handle bone and parent it again with automatic weights.

You could also remove the weight for this bone manually with weight-painting.